# CronTab - Not Working

Tags: cron

I seem to be having problems with crontab, the following works correctly

```
* * * * * TERM="xterm";/usr/bin/lynx -dump http://myurl.com
```

However, when I try scheduling one in for every Sunday at 20:40

```
*/40 */20 * * 0 TERM="xterm";/usr/bin/lynx -dump http://myurl.com
```

It doesn't work, is there something wrong with my syntax? I actually used a generator to write this.

I'm running CentOS, the cronjob should visit a PHP page that then uploads to DropBox - visiting the URL via the browser works. I'm validating my results by checking the dropbox uploaded timestamp on the file.

**UPDATE - For some reason, using CURL instead worked fine :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read up on the cron syntax. You want:

```
40 20 * * 0
```

Explanation:

```
*    *    *    *    *        command to be executed
^    ^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |    |
|    |    |    |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|    |    |    +------- month (1 - 12)
|    |    +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
|    +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to be working, in fact this was the first one I tried.

Comment: Then your syntax isn't the problem. You haven't provided any information about your system (what OS, what version of cron, whether this is in a crontab, how you're testing, etc). You may want to amend your question, otherwise you won't get much more help.

Comment: To be sure that it is cron that is not working, could you change your entry to do something like "date > /tmp/log.txt"? If that file doesn't get written to, then you know it is an issue with cron. Otherwise it might be an issue with lynx or how it retrieves your page.

Comment: It writes out to the log file: date > /tmp/log.txt = Mon Mar 31 21:27:11 BST 2014

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [cron syntax checker](http://cronchecker.net/)

It said

> The command TERM="xterm";/usr/bin/lynx -dump http://myurl.com will execute every 40 minutes of every 20 hours on of every month.

Which isn't what you're wanting I think.

The slashes you are using make increments of ranges. See [cron special characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Special_characters)